# why does it keep showing me an error on exists()?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm developing an opensource program , I need to find out the error here.
This is a linux-meant BASH script.

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a dependenciesList=(
  "element2"
  "element3"
  "element4"
)

#check des dependences dans le systeme actuel:
#____________procedure de verification de l'existance de la dependance
exists ()
{
  command -v "$1" >/dev/null 2>&1
}

#____________procedure de l'installation de la dependance
install ()
{
  echo "[INSTALL] '$1' installation started"
  apt-get install "$1"
}

#____________procedure coeur
for i in "${dependenciesList[@]}"
do
  echo "[CHECK] Verification de l'existance de la dependence : $i"
  # or do whatever with individual element of the array
  if exists "$i"; then
    echo " $i [OK]"
  else
    echo "[CHECK][ERROR][CRITICAL] Le systeme n'a pas $i ,appel a la procedure d'installation "
    install "$i"
  fi
done
```

The code blocks at the function exits always , and returns this error log:

```
./linux.dependencies.check.bash:  syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'/linux.dependencies.check.bash: `exists ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saved your script with Windows line endings (`\r\n` instead of just `\n`), which is confusing the Linux program bash. Run `dos2unix` on the script to fix it.